# Why are my CSS grid items stacking on top of each other?

Tags: css, layout, css-grid

I am having some trouble with CSS grid and items stacking on top of each other when I assign them to grid template areas, I'm fairly new to CSS grid so I might be missing some fundamentals. I have made a playground here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xvg84cuh/

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left right"
    ". right";
}
.grid div:nth-child(1){
  grid-area: left;
}
.grid div:nth-child(2),
.grid div:nth-child(3){
  grid-area: right;
}

div{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    Image
  </div>
  <div>
    Stuff 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Stuff 2
  </div>
</div>
```

where you can see that "stuff 1" and "stuff 2" div's are stacking on top of each other instead of appearing below each other in order.

Thanks for you help :)

Comment: because they are assigned to the *same* area

Comment: But there are multiple instances of the area name so aren't they cascaded down? :S

Comment: No. Contiguous grid areas of the same name are "merged" into one, like how you merge cells in Excel.

Comment: Okay thanks for the that input :) Have noted it down and will not be repeating same mistake :) thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are stacked because you have added the same grid-area property to second and third child

```css
.grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "left right"
    ". third-right";
}
.grid div:nth-child(1){
  grid-area: left;
}
.grid div:nth-child(2){
  grid-area: right;
}
.grid div:nth-child(3){
  grid-area: third-right;
}

div{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    Image
  </div>
  <div>
    Stuff 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Stuff 2
  </div>
</div>
```

For more knowledge of `grid-template-area` and `grid-area` refer:
[grid-template-area](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-template-areas.asp)
[grid-area](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-area.asp)

Comment: Thanks for solution! :) I got a indepth explanation in the comments for my first post aswell! But appreciate it :)